# Report using RDLC can't load dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, report, error-reporting

I am trying to make an report using `RDLC` file .I am following this link :

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/13169999-ef3b-496c-b502-caef973c3bb2/?Using%20ReportViewer%20in%20WinForms%20C

So i create a RDLC file an import my `tax` object to this report my tax ubject has a structure like this :

```
public partial class Tax
    {
        public Tax()
        {
            this.Innovices = new HashSet<Inovice>();
        }
        [DisplayName("شناسه")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("عوارض شهرداری")]
        public Nullable<double> MunicipalTax { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("مالیات بر ارزش افزوده")]
        public Nullable<double> AdditionalTax { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("سال مالی")]
        public string Year { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Inovice> Innovices { get; set; }
    }
```

Here you can see binding object to my report :

[image]

I put a reportviewer in y form and i write this code in `formload

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InvoiceRepository.TaxRepository obj = new TaxRepository();
            List<InnoviceDomainClass.Tax> list = obj.GetAll().ToList();

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); //clear report
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Factor169.Report.Report1.rdlc";
                // bind reportviewer with .rdlc

            Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource dataset =
                new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Dataset1", list); // set the datasource
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
            dataset.Value = list;

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); // refresh report
        }`
```

But after executing  the result is like this :why ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource dataset =
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("Dataset1", list);
```

Should be **DataSet1**

```
ReportDataSource("DataSet1", list); //The "s"
```

The name of the report datasource must be the same as the dataset in the report.